# I have fetched data from Google places api, issue in storing those values to DB using php

Tags: php, arrays

[Please refer, I have attached an image of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HmeE.png)

How can I get address_components array? I tried to access like

-=-=-=**View**-=-=-=-=

```
 function fillInAddress() {
                            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();                    
                            for (var component in componentForm) {
                                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
                            }
                            var values_after = JSON.stringify(place);

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Search/add_user_details", 
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {values:values_after},
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(result)
                                {
                                    $("#div1").html(result);
                                }
                            });

                        }
```

-=-=-=**Controller**-=-=-=-=

```
public function add_user_details()
        {
            $respStatus = 200;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            if($response['status'] == $respStatus)
            {
                $params = $this->input->post();
                if (empty($params))
                {
                    $respStatus = 400;
                    $resp = array('status' => 400,'message' =>  'No data found');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $resp = $this->Search_model->add_user_details($params);
                }
                json_output($respStatus,$resp);
            }
        }
```

-=-=-=-=-=-**Model**-=-=-=-=-=

```
public function add_user_details($values)
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($values['formatted_address']);
            $data = array(
            'user_id' => 2,
            'location' => $values['formatted_address']
            );
            $result = $this->db->insert('places',$data);
            if($result)
            {
                return array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Successfully Inserted');
            }
            else
            {
                return json_output(401,array('status' => false,'message' => 'Please try again later')); 
            }
        }
```

$values['address_components'];
it says, undefined index.

```
{
    "address_components": [
        {
            "long_name": "Chennai",
            "short_name": "Chennai",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Chennai",
            "short_name": "Chennai",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Tamil Nadu",
            "short_name": "TN",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "India",
            "short_name": "IN",
            "types": [
                "country",
                "political"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "adr_address": "Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",
    "formatted_address": "Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India"
}
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($values['formatted_address']);
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

How to solve this issue? somebody please help me.

Comment: How is `$values` defined?

Comment: @Teemu can you help me now?

Comment: Still, without knowing what your controller returns from its post method, this not solvable. Most likely you're getting a JSON string, and you have to decode it to PHP array before trying to access it.

Comment: @Teemu I stringfy data before passing to controller. Can you check now? I have updated.

Comment: Yse, please re-read the last sentence in my previous comment.

Comment: json_decode($values,true) like this?

Comment: Pretty much like that, though you might want to assign the value returned from `json_decode` to a variable ... JSON is a textual data interchange format. In practice it looks and acts like a string. It is language independent, and many languages can understand it after parsing it to the native form in each language. In PHP you use `json_decode` function to convert a JSON string to a PHP array. Even JavaScript can't access a JSON string without parsing it to JS object first.